# SSIS 2012 connection manager red arrow

Tags: ssis

I have project where there is allready connection manager created called ODS, and this connection manager used domain account before, now I have to switch it to user and password, the problem is that when I simple go to edit and change it doesn't work, but when I create new then it works. I saw that there are two icons near the connection manager, red arrow and fx , what does it mean ?

Edit:
OK I assume that fx means that it is parametrized and red arrow means problem with connection. Unfortunally there seems to be a bug, when connection manager is paramterized and there is connection string in parameter it doesn't work locally.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was to take connection manager ofline and connection manager worked for me in this format `Data Source=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Auto Translate=False;`

Answer (score 2):

Cause:

Your connection manager goes offline when you make a change to the connection string that is incorrect, ex. spelling error in the server name, and the system can not validate the connection.

To fix it:

1. Correct the mistake in the connection string
2. Right click on the connection in the connection manager and un-select the "Work OffLine" option. This remove the "Red Arrow" icon and make your connection "live" again.

Answer (score 0):

The red downward facing arrow indicates that the resource the connection manager is using is offline or unreachable in some fashion.

I believe you are stating that when you manually edit the connection manager, it doesn't work/persist and that is due to the Expression overriding the values. To resolve this, right click on your project level ODS Connection Manager and choose properties. Click the plus sign on the Expressions property and from there, you can identify the Variables and/or Parameters that are actually setting the values.

A Variable will take the form of `@[Schema::VariableName]`

A package level parameter will take the form of `@[$Package::ParameterName]`

A project level parameter will take the form of `@[$Project::ParameterName]`

Once you have identified the source of the Expression, then you will go to the Variables Pane (View -> Other Windows, Variables); Parameters tab at the top of the package; Projects.params and change the values there.

If all of that has the correct values, then you may be running into an incompatibility with your Project and packages' Protection Level. If it's DontSaveSensitive, clicking Save might result in the password being removed. I haven't worked with SQL Logins for some time so I don't know for sure how they will behave. You *might* be able to set the password, if it's a parameter, as Sensitive and see if that doesn't make it better. Might make it worse as there are strict rules about how you access a Sensitive parameter versus a non-sensitive.

Finally, the `fx` glyph signifies there is an expression *somewhere* on the connection manager. While it's likely on the `ConnectionString` or the individual components of database name, user and password, I've seen people use expressions on more esoteric properties.

Comment: I did it already before, I set right connection string for parameter which is used for expression for connectoin manager, but somehow ssis doesn't use this value